# view trac on mobile devices (iphone, android, etc)

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, project-management, trac

Our team uses Trac heavily for project management, and I need to view the Trac site from time to time. Yet, it's really inconvenient to view the Trac site from the mobile device (it's an iphone in my case).

I wonder if there is any existing hack / plugin / template / css suite that could help display Trac better on the mobile devices? I thought some `<meta>` tags and css positioning should make the trick, yet I could not google out much from this.

any help is appreciated.

thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Consider reading [TracInterfaceCustomization in Trac's wiki](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization) for a start, more specifically [about using style.css](http://trac.edgewall.org/intertrac/wiki%3aCookBook/SiteStyleCss) as I agree that you'll certainly need to change site-wide styles.

Ready-made themes are available at [trac-hacks.org](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/theme). Maybe you'll find something suiting your need at least a bit better than Trac default for a quicker start.

And finally the [ThemeEnginePlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ThemeEnginePlugin) seems like a great tool to put your ideas into reality quickly, although I've never tested this on my own by now. Good luck.

Comment: thx hasienda, I actually checked trac hacks > themes section before, but I could not find any theme that is related to the mobiles, did I overlook something? Just want to make sure I would not re-invent the wheels before I start to tune up the CSS.

Comment: Confirmed, I checked before answering here too, but there has been nothing specifically related to mobile clients. So your contribution would be very welcome to fill in this obvious gap.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it took me a while to work out this. This is not perfect, neither good, but at least it looks a little better for me.

here is what I have done:

in the folder of `[trac root]/templates/`, add or edit the `site.html`, which contains the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/" py:strip="">

  <head py:match="head" py:attrs="select('@*')">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

${select('*|comment()|text()')}

<link media="handheld, screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/htdocs-trac/css/trac-mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>
  <!--! Custom match templates go here -->
</html>
```

the above would add a new CSS link of `/htdocs-trac/css/trac-mobile.css` for every Trac page, and then u could put the mobile-device-only styles inside the css file, in my case, the css file contains:

```
.nav li {
    white-space: normal;
}

#mainnav *:link, #mainnav *:visited {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#mainnav *:link, #mainnav *:visited {
  padding: 0 0px;
}

#header h1 {
margin: 0;

}
```

honestly, it ONLY makes the title bar appeared better, and the button not collided. But a lot of places use table based layout, and (seems) could not be solved by css easily.

Hope it helps for others.